# Adding borders and margins to a semantic HTML table using CSS without changing markup

Tags: html, css, html-table, styled-components

I have mocked up my issue on a fiddle.

My table current has all of the right pieces, but I'm trying to add a "border" to the bottom of the `styled-head` so that it clearly differentiates from the rows and then adding top & bottom lines to the rows (depending on if they require it, for example, the first row should not need a top border because the head should always have one). I have tried adding borders but they don't appear. I dont want to add any new HTML elements to the markup, is it possible to achieve these changes with just CSS?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wgv2ohy/19/ (I have just created this to re-create my issue quickly)

```css
.styled-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px 8px;
  max-width: 1248px;
}

.styled-head {
  display: table-header-group;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.styled-link {
  display: table-cell;
  
}

.styled-rows {
  display: table-row-group;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.styled-row {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  display: table-row;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.styled-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #27282a;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-table">

  <div class="styled-head">
    <a class="styled-link">Ford</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volkswagen</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volvo</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="styled-rows">
  
    <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Fiesta</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Golf</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Galaxy</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Polo</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX50</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `border-bottom` CSS to following **`a`** attribute inside `styled-head`

```css
.styled-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px 8px;
  max-width: 1248px;
}

.styled-head {
  display: table-header-group;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.styled-head a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
  
.styled-link {
  display: table-cell;
  
}

.styled-rows {
  display: table-row-group;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.styled-row {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  display: table-row;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.styled-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #27282a;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-table">
  <div class="styled-head">
    <a class="styled-link">Ford</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volkswagen</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volvo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-rows">
    <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Fiesta</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Golf</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Galaxy</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Polo</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX50</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Added `border-bottom: 1px solid black` to the `.styled-link`.

```css
.styled-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: seperate;
  border-spacing: 0px 8px;
  max-width: 1248px;
}

.styled-head {
  display: table-header-group;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.styled-link {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.styled-rows {
  display: table-row-group;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.styled-row {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  display: table-row;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.styled-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #27282a;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-table">
  <div class="styled-head">
    <a class="styled-link">Ford</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volkswagen</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volvo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-rows">
    <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Fiesta</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Golf</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Galaxy</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Polo</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX50</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add style to a `thead`tag, so, using the `display` property the div act like a `thead`.
You can achieve the results, adding the style to the content of `<div class="styled-head">`

```css
.styled-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px 8px;
  max-width: 1248px;
}

.styled-head {
  display: table-header-group;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black; // <==== You can remove this
}

.styled-link {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; // Add this
  
}

.styled-rows {
  display: table-row-group;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.styled-row {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  display: table-row;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.styled-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #27282a;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-table">
  <div class="styled-head">
    <a class="styled-link">Ford</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volkswagen</a>
    <a class="styled-link">Volvo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="styled-rows">
    <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Fiesta</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Golf</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX30</span>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="styled-row">
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Galaxy</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>Polo</span>
      </div>
      <div class="styled-cell">
        <span>CX50</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```